# BootstrapVue message box input press `Enter` to confirm

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, jsx, bootstrap-vue

Vue: `v2.6.12`
BootstrapVue: `v2.21.2`

Instead of manually clicking `OK`, how to press `Enter` to confirm?

```js
let text
this.$bvModal.msgBoxConfirm(<input vModel={text} />)
```

[image]

Comment: I use Vue and Bootstrap, but not BootstrapVue.  Conceptually, if you can bind an event handler to your msgBoxConfirm ```<input>```, then when you receive an enter key event, call the 'OK' button event handler.

Comment: @Tim Yes, but afaik, the _"'OK' button event handler"_ is not exposed

Comment: @Tim I've solved this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured this out:

```js
const modalId = 'modalId'

const ok = () => this.$bvModal.hide(modalId)

let text

this.$bvModal.msgBoxConfirm(<input vModel={text} vOn:keyup_enter={ok} />, {
  id: modalId,
})
```